# How to connect to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, d

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 with C#, but I wonder how can I connect to them using D...

I did a google search and found this: http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?DatabaseBindings

But I found nothing about connecting to SQL Server...

Comment: You should be able to connect through ODBC - I see that in the list of D libraries.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `OpenDBX` bindings available here: https://github.com/rikkimax/Derelict_Extras---OpenDBX. `OpenDBX` provides access to multiple db servers , using a unified interface, including `MS SQL Server`, `PostgreSQL`, `SQLite` and others.

It has a C api so it is not very pretty, but it should work.

Another option is to use ODBC. Bindings are available at https://github.com/AndrejMitrovic/DWinProgramming.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a binding/wrapper for FreeTDS: http://www.freetds.org/ . That is the best, open-source library you can use to connect to the SQL server. An alternative would perhaps be unixODBC and iODBC, but as far as I know they both use FreeTDS for Microsoft SQL Server.